# Restore Podcast Layout in iTunes 12.4

Tags: itunes, podcasts

My Macbook Pro just updated its iTunes to 12.4, and now I cannot figure out how to navigate my Podcasts. In the previous version, I had a list of Podcasts in the sidebar, and I could select one to see a list of all current and previous episodes. Now all I see is "Most Recent" and everything is jumbled together in one list.

Is there a way to restore the previous behavior of listing the Podcasts individually?

Relevant screenshots:
[image: iTunes 12.2] [image: iTunes 12.4]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the sidebar at the top you have the **Podcasts** option (just above the **Stations** one you have just selected) which seems to do what you want - you will see a list of all of your podcasts in the middle column. Then you can switch between unplayed/feed tabs in the right column to see all episodes or just the unplayed ones.

Depending on the defaults the view might be reduced to a text-only list.

Edit including comment from @JosephLeedy:

In order to obtain the three column view similar to the old look, after clicking on "Podcasts," you have to go to `View` > `View Options` in the menu (or press <kbd>⌘J</kbd>) and change `View As` from `Classic List` to `List`.

Comment: I saw that list, but it is extremely hard to read on a small screen. I just want to get the old layout back if that is possible. I might have to find a way to downgrade iTunes...

Comment: After clicking on "Podcasts," you have to go to `View > View Options` (or press <kbd>⌘J</kbd>) and change "View As" from "Classic List" to "List". Thanks!

Comment: @JosephLeedy I came here because I had the same problem, and your comment above solved it for me.  You should post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @mweiss Thanks! Originally it was an answer, but then I deleted it and made it a comment so that I could give Josef Legény the "accept".